# Newtonsoft JSON ignore property if another property is set

Tags: c#, json, json.net, attributes

I have a somewhat complex data class and in it are some properties that are related to each other. A very simple Boolean indicates whether the equally complex subclass, which is one of the properties, is used at all. This subclass uses a LOT of space in the json file and I would love to only set those values that are needed.

Normally I would just go through the code and set the complex subclass to null and add a "JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)" as an attribute to the property. But the code is really complex and I would prefer to use an attribute and say something like "Ignore if the Boolean is `false`".

Is this possible? Maybe with a `JsonConverter` or something the like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should use the Conditional Property Serialization based on  `ShouldSerialize`

So if you have a class like this;

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public bool AddressPopulated { get; set; }
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

  //Add should serialise here
}
```

And you only want to serialise if `AddressPopulated` is set to true, then you use this option on all the properties which are conditional and add them into your class above.  Like this.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeStreet1() { return AddressPopulated; }
public bool ShouldSerializeStreet2() { return AddressPopulated; }
public bool ShouldSerializeCity() { return AddressPopulated; }
public bool ShouldSerializePostcode() { return AddressPopulated; }
```

See also the documentation

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm